# Does Magento 2 Enterprise aka Commerce only work if my theme is based on luma theme?

Tags: magento2, theme, magento2-enterprise, magento-2-commerce

One of our subcompanies plans to upgrade to Magento 2 Commerce. Their agency claims they have to reprogramm our theme to make it based of of the Luma theme, otherwise it won't work with enterprise/commerce, as they claim. They ask for a couple of hundred thousand € to upgrade to commerce.

In my eyes this is totally bs and makes no sense. I upgraded our test site of another shop where the theme is based on luma, and I did not had to change anything in the theme or extensions, it just worked out of the box. I also switched to magento/base and the enterprise features were still present. Why should it only work with luma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Luma or Blank themes should work fine for either version of Magento.

They may need to make some changes to the theme to incorporate any new functionality but I wouldn't see that as a huge amount of effort although it will vary based on the theme.

Comment: Thank you. They claimed they will need about 300 person days to upgrade... lol